# R: identify the factor associated with the highest sum of values for multiple groups

Tags: r, aggregate

Consider this:

```
plot=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B")
mean=c(3,5,40,0,3,5,3,0)
sp=c("ch","ch","ag",NA,"ch","ag","ch",NA)
df=data.frame(plot,mean,sp)

  plot mean   sp
1    A    3   ch
2    A    5   ch
3    A   40   ag
4    A    0 <NA>
5    B    3   ch
6    B    5   ag
7    B    3   ch
8    B    0 <NA>
```

I'd like to figure out some code that will return the "sp" from each "plot" with the highest cumulative "mean" value.  For the example above, I'd like to return this:

```
plot=c("A","B")
sp=c("ag","ch")
df=data.frame(plot,sp)

  plot sp
1    A ag
2    B ch
```

In case that wasn't clear, for plot A, the sp "ag" is returned becasue it has the highest cumulative mean value (40) for the plot.  For plot B, "ch" is returned because it has the highest cumulative value (6). The values are not important to me; I want only the most dominant sp by cumulative mean value for each plot.

I've played around with aggregate and suspect that would be useful here, but am unsure about how to proceed.

Many thanks (this site is a huge resource for those of us new to R!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this in two steps.

Step 1, aggregate the data frame by plot at sp and calculate the cummulative mean. You can use a package such as plyr with ddply or the dplyr package for this.

Step 2, once you've done this, for each plot output the sp with the highest cumulative mean. There are a lot of ways to to this. I'd again go with dplyr, but that's because I'm a bit besotted with it at the moment.

Actually...you can do this whole thing with 4 lines in dplyr with one line per operation piping your way through with magritr. 5 if you want to get rid of the cumulative means column. You just need a group_by, summarise, and filter statement. I'll post the code if you want it, but it will be far more useful for you to go read, say, http://seananderson.ca/2014/09/13/dplyr-intro.html and try it yourself.

Or....

```
df %>%
  group_by(plot, sp) %>%
  summarise(cumMean = sum(mean, na.rm=T)) %>%
  filter(cumMean == max(cumMean)) %>% 
  select(plot, sp)
```

Comment: Thanks.  The code in your edit was the first that I was able to get to work with my data so I went with it.  I will spend some timing getting familiar with dplyr--thanks for the work-through in logic and advice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that uses the "data.table" package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, cumsum(mean), by=.(plot, sp)][, .(sp = sp[V1 == max(V1)]), by=plot]
#    plot sp
# 1:    A ag
# 2:    B ch
```

After setting `df` to a data table with `setDT(df)`, we are doing two things

1. `[, cumsum(mean), by=.(plot, sp)]` calculates the cumulative sum of the `mean` column, grouped by `plot` and `sp`
2. `[, .(sp = sp[V1 == max(V1)]), by=plot]` takes the `sp` value for which `V1` (calculated in step 1) is equal to the maximum of `V1` and renames that column `sp`, grouped by `plot`

Comment: Thanks, Richard.  Your solution worked great on my simple data set, but a strange thing happened when I applied it to my real data.  I have quite a few plots with only 0s for "mean" values and only NAs for "sp" values; for those plots, this solution returns a row with an NA for each row in that plot.  I should have had the foresight to include a plot with only 0/NAs in my example.  It's probably not a difficult fix, but @jebyrnes advice got me where I wanted to be so I didn't play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how @jebyrnes would have done it with `summarise` and `filter` (edit: I figured it out and it's pretty simple too), but here's how I'd go about it with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, plot,sp) %>% summarise(sum=sum(mean)) %>% summarise(sp=sp[sum==max(sum)])
#  plot sp
#1    A ag
#2    B ch
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate twice: once to calculate the sums for each `plot` and `sp`, and a second time to get the maxima for each `plot`. The second aggregation is only going to give you the mean, though, so merge it back in with the first aggregate.

```
df2 = aggregate(mean ~ plot + sp, FUN = sum, data = df)
df3a = aggregate(mean ~ plot, data = df2, FUN = max)
merge(df3a, df2)
```

I haven't tested what happens if you have equal sums coming up here, though. Also, this drops any NAs in the data frame. If you want to keep those, I'd make sure you bring the data frame in with strings rather than factors and then changing the NAs to placeholders (`"None"` or even `"NA"`) before you begin. The above code works fine with strings!

```
df = data.frame(plot,mean,sp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df[is.na(df$sp), "sp"] = "None"

> df
  plot mean   sp
1    A    3   ch
2    A    5   ch
3    A   40   ag
4    A    0 None
5    B    3   ch
6    B    5   ag
7    B    3   ch
8    B    0 None
```

Comment: Thanks.  Should `df[is.na(df$sp), "sp"] = "None"` be `df[is.na(df$sp), "NA"] = "None"`?  The latter worked for me, but the former did not (probably my own ignorance!).  I failed to mention in my example that my data includes many plots with only 0s for "mean" values and only NAs for "sp" values.  This code seems to ignore those plots.  My fault for not mentioning their existence.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear that! The latter definitely shouldn't (and, for me, doesn't) work. The reason is that `df[X, Y] = "None"` is targeting cells of `df` with row `X` and column `Y`. `X` is a condition for us: rows whose `sp` column is `NA`. `Y` targets columns named `sp`.

Comment: Basically, using your latter code, you'll end up with a new column called `"NA"`; mine overwrites the `NA`s in the `sp` column. Think of this operation as *selecting* rows (based on `is.nsa()`) and then *editing* columns.